# Overriding getCustomSearchContext is not working in silverstripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have created an `Album` `DataObject`, as below, to be managed in the cms through `ModelAdmin`.

In the search filter, `Name` is the only input field. I also want to show an `Author` input field.

So I have tried to override the `getCustomSearchContext()` function but this is not working.

```php
class Album extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Name' => 'Varchar(200)',
        'Author' => 'Varchar(200)',
    );

    private static $has_many = array(
        'Genres' => 'Genre'
    );


    public function getCustomSearchContext() {
        $fields = $this->scaffoldSearchFields(array(
            'restrictFields' => array()
        ));

        $filters = array(
            'Name' => new PartialMatchFilter('Name'),
            'Author' => new PartialMatchFilter('Author')
        );

        return new SearchContext(
            $this->class,
            $fields,
            $filters
        );
    }

}
```

I know we can use `$searchable_fields` but I don't want to use them because I want to customize form fields in the search form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Silverstripe 3.1.5 it looks like `getCustomSearchContext()` does not exist any more. Instead use `getDefaultSearchContext()`.

I also created a `FieldList` and pushed the fields in.

```php
public function getDefaultSearchContext() {
    $fields = new FieldList();
    $fields->push(new TextField('Name', 'Name'));
    $fields->push(new TextField('Author', 'Author'));

    $filters = array(
        'Name' => new PartialMatchFilter('Name'),
        'Author' => new PartialMatchFilter('Author')
    );

    return new SearchContext(
        $this->class,
        $fields,
        $filters
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi, if your not busy, may I ask; how did you find the answer

Comment: Hi Thomas. Good question. After checking the documentation and various testing, I checked the [`DataObject`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DataObject.html#_getDefaultSearchContext) class in Silverstripe api. I noticed there was no `getCustomSearchContext()` function but there was a `getDefaultSearchContext()` function.